# How do I prove that $U(r) \to S(r,n) \to G(r,n)$ is a fibration?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$U(r)$ here is unitary group of $\mathbb{C}^n$, $S(r,n)$ is the Stiefel manifold of $r$-frames in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $G(r,n)$ is the Grassmannian manifold of $r$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^n$.
I've tried a direct proof of the homotopy lifting property, but I can't come out with a direct lifted homotopy.
Obviously $\pi : S(r,n) \to G(r,n)$ is the one that maps $(e_1,\dots, e_r)$ in $e_1 \wedge \dots \wedge e_r$.

Comment: It is a locally trivial fiber bundle over a (para)compact space, thus it is a Hurewicz fibration, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Examples

Comment: Really thank you. Can you post it with some detail as a reply, so I can mark it as solved? I've figured out how to prove that fiber bundles are local trivializations, but any more detail would be useful.